# Combining multiple CompletableFutures

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have the following component:

```
private JobInfo aggregateJobInfo() {
    final JobsResult jobsResult = restClient().getJobs();
    final List<String> jobIds = extractJobIds(jobsResult);

    //fetch details, exceptions and config for each job
    final List<JobDetails> jobDetails = jobIds.stream().map(jobId -> {
        final JobDetailResult jobDetailResult = restClient().getJobDetails(jobId);
        final JobExceptionsResult jobExceptionsResult = restClient().getJobExceptions(jobId);
        final JobConfigResult jobConfigResult = restClient().getJobConfig(jobId);
        return new JobDetails(jobDetailResult, jobExceptionsResult, jobConfigResult);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new JobInfo(jobsResult, jobDetails);
}

private static List<String> extractJobIds(final JobsResult jobsResult) {
    final ArrayList<String> jobIds = new ArrayList<>();
    jobIds.addAll(jobsResult.getRunning());
    jobIds.addAll(jobsResult.getFinished());
    jobIds.addAll(jobsResult.getCanceled());
    jobIds.addAll(jobsResult.getFailed());
    return jobIds;
}
```

It just calls some ENDPOINTS and aggergates some data. Now I'm trying to make that non-blocking by using CompletableFutures, which I didn't really used before..

```
private CompletableFuture<JobInfo> aggregateJobInfo() {
    final CompletableFuture<JobsResult> jobsResultFuture = restClient().getJobs();
    final CompletableFuture<List<String>> jobIdsFuture = jobsResultFuture.thenApply(JobInfoCollector::extractJobIds);

     //fetch details, exceptions and config for each job
    final CompletableFuture<List<CompletableFuture<JobDetails>>> jobDetailsFuture = jobIdsFuture.thenApply(jobIds -> {
        return jobIds.stream().map(jobId -> {
            final CompletableFuture<JobDetailResult> jobDetailsResultFuture = restClient().getJobDetails(jobId);
            final CompletableFuture<JobExceptionsResult> jobExceptionsFuture = restClient().getJobExceptions(jobId);
            final CompletableFuture<JobConfigResult> jobConfigFuture = restClient().getJobConfig(jobId);
            return jobDetailsResultFuture.thenCompose(jobDetailResult -> {
                return jobExceptionsFuture.thenCombine(jobConfigFuture, (jobExceptionsResult, jobConfigResult) -> {
                    return new JobDetails(jobDetailResult, jobExceptionsResult, jobConfigResult);
                });
            });

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
    return null;
```

My problem is how to create CompletableFuture here when JobInfo is `new JobInfo(jobsResult, jobDetails)?!

As I said, I'm new to this, maybe my approach is bad and there are better solutions?

Any ideas appreciated, thanks in

**First working version:**

```
private CompletableFuture<JobInfo> aggregateJobInfo() {

    final CompletableFuture<JobsResult> jobsResultFuture = restClient().getJobs();
    final CompletableFuture<List<String>> jobIdsFuture = jobsResultFuture.thenApply(JobInfoCollector::extractJobIds);

    final CompletableFuture<List<CompletableFuture<JobDetails>>> jobDetailsFutureListFuture =
            jobIdsFuture.thenApply(jobIds -> jobIds.stream().map(jobId -> {
                final CompletableFuture<JobDetailResult> jobDetailsResultFuture = restClient().getJobDetails(jobId);
                final CompletableFuture<JobExceptionsResult> jobExceptionsFuture = restClient().getJobExceptions(jobId);
                final CompletableFuture<JobConfigResult> jobConfigFuture = restClient().getJobConfig(jobId);
                return jobDetailsResultFuture.thenCompose(jobDetailResult ->
                        jobExceptionsFuture.thenCombine(jobConfigFuture, (jobExceptionsResult, jobConfigResult) ->
                                new JobDetails(jobDetailResult, jobExceptionsResult, jobConfigResult)));
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return jobDetailsFutureListFuture.thenCompose(jobDetailsFutures ->
            CompletableFuture.allOf(jobDetailsFutures.toArray(
                    new CompletableFuture[jobDetailsFutures.size()])).thenApply(aVoid ->
                    jobDetailsFutures.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .thenApply(jobDetails -> jobsResultFuture.thenApply(jobsResult ->
                    new JobInfo(jobsResult, jobDetails)))
            .join();
}
```

Comment: It does not seem like most of the code you have pasted is relevant to the question. Can you reduce it to a minimal example of what you need?

Comment: The question was how to "map" the future data above so CompletableFuture<JobInfo> is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

- `CompletableFuture<JobsResult> jobsResultFuture`
- `CompletableFuture<List<CompletableFuture<JobDetails>>> jobDetailsFuture`
- `JobInfo(JobsResult a, List<JobDetails> b)`

You want

`CompletableFuture<JobInfo>`

additional observation: `jobDetailsFuture` can only be completed when `jobsResultFuture` has completed.

So you can implement the following:

1. `List<CompletableFuture<JobDetails>>` -> `Void` via `allOf` in `thenCompose`
2. `Void` + `List<CompletableFuture<JobDetails>>` (as captured var) -> `List<JobDetails>` via `thenApply`
3. `List<JobDetails>` + `CompletableFuture<JobsResult>` (as captured var) -> `JobInfo` via `thenApply`

You can simply unwrap the futures via `get()` inside those mapper functions because the futures are guaranteed to have completed at that point due to the dependencies of their ancestor futures at that point.

Other approaches using `thenCombine` and stream reduction would be possible, but more verbose and create more intermediate futures.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it..What do mean with 'awaitAll' and the Void?

Comment: meant [allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-). It returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, hence the next step to get the data back

Comment: Still don't understand. Tried
        jobDetailsListFuture.thenCompose(jobDetailsFutures -> {
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(jobDetailsFutures.toArray(
                    new CompletableFuture[jobDetailsFutures.size()]))
                    .thenApply(aVoid -> { ??? });
        });

but don't know what to do with the void.

Comment: you do nothing with it, the second part matters

Comment: Think of the completeable futures as two separate flows of information: Completions/computation progress and the carried data objects. Sometimes you are only interested in the completion and not the data so you can know when you can safely call `get()` without blocking or exceptions, possibly on different Futures than the one that completes.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much!! I finally made it work, see above, although I have to admit that I don't completely understand yet, but I still have to take a deeper look into the cp-api. And I guess there's much space for improvements, but for now I'm fine..